# Simple CheckBoxList displays model hierarchy not values

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am a newbie and trying to build a website, I have a simple CheckBoxList control on a page that at the moment is displaying some 'Category' data. However I want to reduce the records to be grouped by a field within the data called 'CategoryType'.

aspx code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetCategories"> /asp:CheckBoxList>
```

aspx.cs code:

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories()
{
   var _db = new YPGOOS2.Models.YPGOOSDataContext();
   IQueryable<Category> query = _db.Categories;
   return query;
}
```

I have a table called "Categories" in the database and a DataContext class called YPGOOSDataContext.cs which includes:

```
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

All I want to do is put in a groupby clause that groups on CategoryType so I can display that data in the CheckBoxList.

I can enter a subsequent OrderBy statement that sorts the data correctly...

```
query = query.OrderBy(ob=>ob.CategoryType); //this sorts by CategoryType correctly
```

...however when I try the following it doesn't work...

```
query = query.GroupBy(gb => gb.CategoryType); //can't get the GroupBy to work!!
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
query = query.GroupBy(gb => gb.CategoryType).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

`GroupBy` not directly return `IQueryable<Category>`, you need to build it depending on your requirements

Comment: Awesome thank you @Damith, that worked with a slight modification... query = query.GroupBy(gb => gb.CategoryType).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: @skella FirstOrDefault will be more suitable.

Comment: Hmmm it seems all of a sudden I get a red squiggly line under _db.Categories and the following error when running that code "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<YPGOOS2.Models.Category>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<YPGOOS2.Category>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) does anyone know what that is?

Comment: OK that seems to have been fixed by the following...         public IQueryable<YPGOOS2.Models.Category> GetCategoryTypes()
        {
            var _db = new YPGOOS2.Models.YPGOOSDataContext();
            IQueryable<YPGOOS2.Models.Category> query = _db.Categories;
            query = query.GroupBy(gb => gb.CategoryType).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
            return query;
        }